# How to use aboguous unnamed colum in Oracle PL/SQL cursor FOR loop?

Tags: oracle, for-loop, indexing, cursor

My cursor is defined as follows:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cLoop IS 
   SELECT refcl ||'_TEST' FROM t_select;
BEGIN
  FOR rI IN cLoop LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Test: ' || rI.XXXXXXXX);
  END LOOP;
END
```

The cursor will give the following (for example):

```
A9028ZQ7_TEST
A9028ZQA_TEST
A9028ZQB_TEST
```

When you take a look I did not define a new column for the expression `"refcl ||'_TEST'"` ( with using the "`SELECT exp AS column_name`" ) and therefore I cannot address the dynamic field data created.

Do you guys know what should I probably put in the place of the XXXXXXXX ?

Comment: Just a note, the column name is not dynamic.  It has a fixed name.  The name is just rather esoteric.

Comment: ...give the expression an alias and then you won't have this problem? I am probably missing something but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a derived column, its a must to `alias` it. You simply cannot use it without aliasing. So the solution of your problem will be.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cLoop IS 
   SELECT refcl ||'_TEST' col1 FROM t_select;
BEGIN
  FOR rI IN cLoop 
   LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Test: ' || rI.col1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Or the second option is to make the dervied column when you are displaying it as below:

```
DECLARE
      CURSOR cLoop IS 
       SELECT refcl FROM t_select;
    BEGIN
      FOR rI IN cLoop 
       LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Test: ' || rI.refc1||'_TEST');
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a poor idea to write code without using column aliases.  You really want to alias the column name.

If you are really, really determined to avoid using an alias for some reason, you could use

```
rI."REFCL||'_TEST'"
```

but I'm going to wager that if you do, whoever has to support your code later will hate you.